# Click on all elements with the same id-resource in scrollable screen

Tags: java, android, appium

I am writing a testcase to check if all elements available on a scrollable screen can be clicked and getting stuck on how to let the code know if that element is executed (clicked) or not since its attribute are the same with others, the only difference is the instance attribute.

[image]

There are more element with the same attribute below.
Can anyone suggest me the way to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First get the text of the movie or thumbnail you want to click into hashset and scroll to which ever direction where you find the more thumbnails and again get the text and save it into hashset (will remove if any duplicate values are there) and then since you have text of all the thumbnails you can get the clickable image using the name in xpath and you can click each.

This approach you get to test all the images present in the screen whether clickable or not